# Python comparison operator

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I can't figure out why my if-else statement doesn't run as expected. I've tried to create code to test for a palindromic string. My print functions show me that the reverse method works, but when I get to the comparison stage I can't get it to return True.

Here is the code:

```
def is_palindrome(a):
    myList = []

    for i in a:
        myList.append(i)

    print myList
    new = myList.reverse()
    print myList
    print new

    if myList == new:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print is_palindrome("radar")
```

This returns False. I have also tried changing the if statement to `if myList is new:` but unfortunately it still returns False.

Any insight appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.reverse()` is in-place, meaning it reverses the list it is called upon but doesn't return anything.

The line `print new` should print `None`, and therefore `myList == new` will be `False`.

Instead, use `[::-1]` which is not in-place and returns a new, reversed list, or use an easier way to detect a palindrome, for example:

```
def is_palindrome(iterable):
    return iterable == iterable[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the concept of in-place, but why doesn't it return/ save that list to the variable `new`? EDIT: Just saw your followup, thank you!

Comment: @arumiat Because by definition, when a method is "in-place" it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @arumiat Because the line `new = myList.reverse()` doesn't return anything, it just changed myList. I'm not sure you do understand the concept...

Comment: @DeepSpace okay, but `reversed` does not return a new list... so the comparison won't work...

Comment: @DeepSpace nope - it never has in 2.x or 3.x... (sounds like you're confusing it with `map`/`zip` etc... differences between 2 and 3)

Comment: And you could eliminate copy altogether:

  def is_palindrome(seq):
      return all(x == y for x, y in zip(iter(seq), reversed(seq)))

Comment: And you could eliminate duplicated comparisons:
def is_palindrome(seq):                                                         
    return all(seq[i] == seq[-i-1] for i in range(len(seq) / 2))